# PowerBi embed report filter not working in powerapps

Tags: powerbi, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to embed the powerBi report in powerapps.report was loaded and the pagenavigation also working.comig to filter it's not working.i tried allow new api true but still struggling with that

"embedded url&$filter=tablename/Col name eq 'value''&pagename=report section"

Comment: Do you have any [Special characters in table and column names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-url-filters#special-characters-in-table-and-column-names) ?